# Unity marching cubes issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hlsl, marching-cubes

I am currently trying to implement marching cubes algorhytm and  something goes wrong so it proceedes only one row of desired space.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsRda.png)
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

c#  code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using UnityEngine;

public class NoiseGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0,1)] public float ISO;
    ComputeBuffer _weightsBuffer;
    public ComputeShader NoiseShader;

    [SerializeField] float noiseScale = 0.08f;
    [SerializeField] float amplitude = 200;
    [SerializeField] float frequency = 0.004f;
    [SerializeField] int octaves = 6;
    [SerializeField, Range(0f, 1f)] float groundPercent = 0.2f;


    private void Awake() {
        CreateBuffers();
    }

    private void OnDestroy() {
        ReleaseBuffers();
    }

    public float[] GetNoise() {
        float[] noiseValues =
            new float[GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk * GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk * GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk];

        NoiseShader.SetBuffer(0, "_Weights", _weightsBuffer);
       //NoiseShader.SetInts("ChunkId",chunkId);
        NoiseShader.SetInt("_ChunkSize", GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk);
        NoiseShader.SetFloat("_NoiseScale", noiseScale);
        NoiseShader.SetFloat("_Amplitude", amplitude);
        NoiseShader.SetFloat("_Frequency", frequency);
        NoiseShader.SetInt("_Octaves", octaves);
        NoiseShader.SetFloat("_GroundPercent", groundPercent);


        NoiseShader.Dispatch(
            0, GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk / GridMetrics.NumThreads, GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk / GridMetrics.NumThreads, GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk / GridMetrics.NumThreads
        );

        _weightsBuffer.GetData(noiseValues);

        return noiseValues;
    }

    void CreateBuffers() {
        _weightsBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(
            GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk * GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk * GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk, sizeof(float)
        );
    }

    void ReleaseBuffers() {
        _weightsBuffer.Release();
    }
}
```

hlsl code(some variables are defined in the includes)

```
#pragma kernel GenerateNoise

#include "Includes\FastNoiseLite.compute"
#include "Includes\MetricsCompute.compute"

RWStructuredBuffer<float> _Weights;

float _NoiseScale;
float _Amplitude;
float _Frequency;
int _Octaves;
float _GroundPercent;


[numthreads(numThreads, numThreads, numThreads)]
void GenerateNoise(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    int3 huh = id;
    fnl_state noise = fnlCreateState();
    noise.noise_type = FNL_NOISE_VALUE_CUBIC;
    noise.fractal_type = FNL_FRACTAL_RIDGED;
    noise.frequency = _Frequency;
    noise.octaves = _Octaves;

    float3 pos = id * _NoiseScale;
    float ground = -pos.y + (_GroundPercent * ChunkSize);
    float n = ground + fnlGetNoise3D(noise, pos.x, pos.y, pos.z) * _Amplitude;
    _Weights[indexFromCoord(huh.x, huh.y, huh.z)] = 1;
}
```

it worked just fine and i havent changed anything but it broke

Comment: sorry, what is the issue?